# Python & Arrays : Search and Add Missing Element in Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, datetime, append

I have a messy array; every element has subelements and every subelement has sub-subelements. My array is;

```
myComplex=[[['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']], [['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '5'], ['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '8']], [['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11'], ['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']]]
```

Let me explain this array;

The Subelements that begins with '03.04.2019'; `['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']`

The Subelements that begins with '26.03.2019'; `['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '8']`, `['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '5']`

The Subelements that begins with '01.04.2019'; `['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11']`, `['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2']`, `['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']`

In `myComplex` above, as you see, every subelements' first sub-subelement is a date. I want to add the missing dates between `01.04.2019` and `05.04.2019` (which are 02.04.2019, 04.04.2019, 05.04.2019 for this list) with sub-subelements like this format;

```
[['02.04.2019', 'George', '0']]
[['04.04.2019', 'George', '0']]
[['05.04.2019', 'George', '0']]
```

So I want the output like this when I enter `print(myComplex)`

```
[[['26.03.2019', 'Micheal', '5'], ['26.03.2019', 'Smith', '8']], [['01.04.2019', 'Jack', '11'], ['01.04.2019', 'Michelle', '2'], ['01.04.2019', 'George', '9']], [['03.04.2019', 'Jack', '7']], [['02.04.2019', 'George', '0']], [['04.04.2019', 'George', '0']], [['05.04.2019', 'George', '0']]]
```

How can I do that? Can you give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using lists, I would suggest entering the data into a pandas DataFrame with a timestamp index and name and value columns and then resample to the desired time period and then complete using ffill.

Answer (score 0):

If your output "must" look like that, then I'd imagine you'll just have to rebuild it manually.  If you're open to working alternatives though, you might find it easier to manage as a dictionary:

```
{date: [[name,number],[name,number]], date2: [[name,number]]}
```

And though it won't matter much to the dictionary, if it has to stay a list array, consider yyyy.mm.dd for easier sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what Iain D said you could have a dictionary

```
my_little_bit_complex_dict = {
    '03.04.2019' : [
                    {'name': 'Jack', 'number': 7}
                    ],
    '26.03.2019' : [
                    {'name': 'Michael', 'number': 7},
                    {'name': 'Smith', 'number': 8}
                    ]
}
```

But to be honest you might want to consider using a database if the amount of data is big

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    somedate DATE,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    numberthingy INTEGER
)
```